# Posicionar elemento encima de otro dentro de divs para este caso

Tags: css

Tengo 2 objectos, un reloj y un boton.
Mi intencion era que cuando se llame a @media para esas resoluciones, se cambie la vista de esos elementos, posiciononando el toogle button encima del reloj, pero no doy , probe varias configuraciones y no consigo ubicarlo ahi.

Dejo aqui el codigo

```css
/* General containers */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.clock-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
}

.button-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

    .clock-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}


.container-clock {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Reloj */
.clock {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("../img/clock.png");
  background-color: #091921;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 4px solid #091921;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 -15px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
    inset 0 -15px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset 0 -15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


.light .clock {
  background: url("../img/clock.png");
  background-color: #d1dae3;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 4px solid #cad3dc;
  box-shadow: -8px -8px 15px rgba(167, 100, 100, 0.5),
    inset 10px 10px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), -8 -8 -8 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
    inset 10 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.clock:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.light .clock:before {
  background: #008eff;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
  position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ff1744;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

.light .mn::before {
  background: #091921;
}

.sc::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #2979ff;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  z-index: 12;
}

/* Boton */
.toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  display: flex;

  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* First toggle btn */

#toggle-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: 0.2s ease background-color, 0.2s ease opacity;
}

#toggle-btn span:before,
#toggle-btn span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease transform, 0.2s ease background-color;
}

#toggle-btn span:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-35px, 0px);
  z-index: 1;
}

#toggle-btn span:after {
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translate(2px, 0px);
  z-index: 0;
}

#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  background-color: #000;
}

#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:active + span {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/*Desplazamiento*/
#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translate(38px, -9px);
}

#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(49px, 0px);
}


@media (min-device-width: 50px) and (max-device-width: 321px)  {
  .clock-box {
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .clock {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

    .clock .hour,
  .hr {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .clock .min,
  .mn {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
  }

  .clock .sec,
  .sc {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  .hr::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #ff1744;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .mn::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  
  .sc::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #2979ff;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 12;
  }
  .container-clock {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .toggle-btn {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    display: flex;
    top:0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-clock" id="container-clock">
        <div class="clock-box">
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="hour">
                    <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="min">
                    <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec">
                    <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="toggle-btn" id="toggle-btn">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[link a codepen](https://codepen.io/jmlgomez73/pen/bGgYEpM)

/*No me dejaba publicar por mucho codigo... Ignorad esto...
Tengo 2 objectos, un reloj y un boton.
Mi intencion era que cuando se llame a @media para esas resoluciones, se cambie la vista de esos elementos, posiciononando el toogle button encima del reloj, pero no doy , probe varias configuraciones y no consigo ubicarlo ahi.*/

Comment: Agrega el código a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: ya esta, de todas formas, no se podrán comprobar los cambios...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo que en el conteiner del botón tiene una dimensión asignada, tendría que estar al 100% de la pantalla, te hice unas modificaciones en el código te subo mi solución:

```css
    /* General containers */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.clock-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
}

.button-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

    .clock-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}


.container-clock {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Reloj */
.clock {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("../img/clock.png");
  background-color: #091921;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 4px solid #091921;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 -15px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
    inset 0 -15px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset 0 -15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


.light .clock {
  background: url("../img/clock.png");
  background-color: #d1dae3;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 4px solid #cad3dc;
  box-shadow: -8px -8px 15px rgba(167, 100, 100, 0.5),
    inset 10px 10px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), -8 -8 -8 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
    inset 10 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.clock:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.light .clock:before {
  background: #008eff;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
  position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ff1744;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

.light .mn::before {
  background: #091921;
}

.sc::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #2979ff;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  z-index: 12;
}

/* Boton */
.toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  display: flex;

  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* First toggle btn */

#toggle-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: 0.2s ease background-color, 0.2s ease opacity;
}

#toggle-btn span:before,
#toggle-btn span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease transform, 0.2s ease background-color;
}

#toggle-btn span:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-35px, 0px);
  z-index: 1;
}

#toggle-btn span:after {
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translate(2px, 0px);
  z-index: 0;
}

#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  background-color: #000;
}

#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:active + span {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/*Desplazamiento*/
#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translate(38px, -9px);
}

#toggle-btn input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(49px, 0px);
}


@media (min-device-width: 50px) and (max-device-width: 321px)  {
  .clock-box {
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .clock {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

    .clock .hour,
  .hr {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .clock .min,
  .mn {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
  }

  .clock .sec,
  .sc {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  .hr::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #ff1744;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .mn::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  
  .sc::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #2979ff;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 12;
  }
  .container-clock {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap-reverse
  }
  .button-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
  }
  .toggle-btn {
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-clock" id="container-clock">
        <div class="clock-box">
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="hour">
                    <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="min">
                    <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec">
                    <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="toggle-btn" id="toggle-btn">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!